# Email Alerting System based on User preferences

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-mail

Any ideas around designing and/or implementing Java based Email alerting system (similar to RSS) which would let users pick the frequency, application type, email content and based on their preferences the alerting system would call a program to generate emails. The program would get the data from the database and populate it in the email body. Now, the question really is how to tie up the two pieces together i.e. based on the user preferences trigger the program for email generation.

Comment: @skaffman: Any specific reason for -1?

Comment: Possibly. Maybe you should ask who it was, rather than assuming it was me?

Comment: Generally "not useful". I can't really imagine anyone searching for anything in this question where they would gain anything out of the question or answer. Its all very high level.

Comment: hey John, did you implement this. I have exactly similar requirements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a pretty simple set of requirements

Scheduled job (cron, DBMS_SCHEDULER, whatever) runs every x minutes.

1. It picks out any user with a
   'next_send_date' in the the next x
   minutes.
2. It picks out what to send them
3. It sends the email
4. It reschedules their 'next_send_date' based on preferences
5. Go to next user.

which of those looks like it is difficult ?

Answer (score 0):

That's what I made out of it: https://github.com/molindo/molindo-notify

Shockingly undocumented code though. If you're interested, just let me know. I'll try to come up with some docs.

Comment: Any recommendation on how to use it?

Comment: @John that recommendation currently would fill several pages as I never had the time to make it ready for general usage. It isn't too much code though, so it shouldn't be impossible to grasp from code only. [NotifyService.notify(Notification)](https://github.com/molindo/molindo-notify/blob/master/src/main/java/at/molindo/notify/NotifyService.java#L79) is a good starting point.

Comment: Ok, let me chew on it. Thanks!